# Weslock Double Locking Deadbolt Impossible to Remove from Door:

Tags: doors, lock

I have an old Weslock double-locking deadbolt which is dying a slow death.[image: Weslock Deadbolt]

After removing the outer mechanism, I attempted to remove the inner mechanism simply by tugging.[image: Inner mechanism]

But I've pulled on it so hard that I'm afraid it's going to damage the door before it comes out.  What can I do to remove it?

Also: I cannot remove the plate on the side of the door either; I could just break it off but I am afraid I won't be able to remove the inner mechanism afterwards and will have destroyed the lock in the process, leaving the house unprotected. [image]

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but you do know that the locking mechanism comes out the edge of the door, right? You can't tug it through the big hole where you removed the locking mechanism. I just mention this since you said that you can't remove the side plate either, but the side plate should come off when you pull the rest of the deadbolt mechanism out the edge of the door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a screw driver through the center hole in the dead bolt and pull with even pressure on both sides of the door, it should pop out.  Some gentle taps with a hammer might help.  You could also try prying it out.

Comment: I already tried using the screwdriver. Are you sure it won't damage the door?

Comment: Am I positive? No, but you have to get it out some way or another.  If you did happen to do a bit of damage to the door, many high security locks require a larger opening so that could be an option since you'd likely remove the damaged material anyways.

Comment: Ok, sounds good.

Comment: +1. I've seen people force-fit hardware in existing holes that were really a bit too small, and the only way to remove it then becomes to apply an equal amount of force in the other direction.